# Issue with window.opener in trusted sites (IE8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, window.opener

Here is my issue: I am opening a popup from the main browser window, where the use logs in to a 3rd party site. After logging in, the popup window is being redirected to our site, where I have to send back a message to the original window.

I am using window.opener for sending the message. Everything works fine in IE*/Firefox/etc, but if the 3rd party site is added to the trusted sites in IE, the window.opener won't work anymore.

Why does this happen? How could this be resolved?

Thanks in advance